# Can I reference an uncommitted input state in a transaction

Tags: corda

When creating a new Transaction can I reference an **uncommitted** State as an input state?

E.g.
Issue new Painting State to the ledger with color attribute set to "Blue".
Before all parties have signed (so Painting state remains uncommitted) I issue a new transaction consuming the uncommitted state as input and new Painting state as output (setting painting color attribute to "Red").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inputs are referenced in transactions using `StateRef`s, which are defined as follows:

```
data class StateRef(val txhash: SecureHash, val index: Int)
```

Where:

- `txhash` is the hash of the transaction that created the input state
- `index` is the index of the input state in the *outputs* of the transaction that created it

If you wanted to create a second transaction consuming an input state before you've committed the first transaction, you could proceed as follows:

- Completely build the first transaction
- Manually construct a `StateRef` based on the first transaction's ID
- Pass this `StateRef` as an input to the second transaction

You could even build an entire transaction chain in this way.

**However...**

Until you commit the first transaction, you will see odd behaviour when you do stuff with the second transaction. For example:

- If you try and `verify` the second transaction, your node will try and use the node's vault to convert all the input `StateRef`s into actual states. This will fail, because you haven't stored the first transaction yet
- If you send the second transaction to a counterparty and they try to resolve its dependency graph, your node will try and retrieve the first transaction from its transaction storage and send it over. Again, this will fail because you haven't stored the first transaction yet

So if you're building a transaction chain in this way without committing each state as you create it, you must be very careful about the order in which you later commit the transactions and what operations you do on the second, third, etc. transaction in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Bit confused because I asked the same question on Slack and got following answer from an R3 rep. "Nothing stops you to do that, but keep in mind that none of these transactions are on the ledger until they are signed and notarised. Only when all these transactions from the chain you created gather all the signatures (validate the contract logic), and are successfully notarised, are they considered on the ledger and can be spent to parties who don’t trust you." Reason I asked the question is to determine how complex integration with Corda is from a system of record.

Comment: Ok, I see where the confusion lies :) Updating my answer above shortly.

Comment: Thanks Joel for the detailed explanation. So in short the subsequent transaction that consumes an output state (of a preceding transaction) will fail if that output state is not committed to the ledger. Makes sense although it makes integration with the DLT complex as a system of record may allow states (e.g. purchase order) to be changed many times irrespective if these states have already been committed on the DLT. How do companies typically deal with this (i.e. a queue on top of the DLT to check if a previous (linear) state has already been consumed prior to posting)?